# ClassDefNotFoundError in my own classes

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, android-2.3-gingerbread

I developed the project in Eclipse, then moved to IntelliJ IDEA CE 12, then moved back to the Eclipse. IDEA had converted it to eclipse project not correctly, so I imported project from existing source and added line

```
<nature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</nature>
```

to the  section. Ok, it compiles successfully, but generates a lot of strange errors for the classes written by me and then crashes.

LogCat output:

```
E/dalvikvm( 9673): Could not find class 'com.capsule.launcher.views.Screen', referenced from method com.capsule.launcher.views.Workspace$1.onPageSelected
W/dalvikvm( 9673): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 458 (Lcom/capsule/launcher/views/Screen;) in Lcom/capsule/launcher/views/Workspace$1;
D/dalvikvm( 9673): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0010
W/dalvikvm( 9673): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/capsule/launcher/views/CellLayout; (346)
W/dalvikvm( 9673): Link of class 'Lcom/capsule/launcher/views/CellLayout;' failed
W/dalvikvm( 9673): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/capsule/launcher/views/DockBar; (455)
W/dalvikvm( 9673): Link of class 'Lcom/capsule/launcher/views/DockBar;' failed
W/dalvikvm( 9673): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/capsule/launcher/views/DockBar;)
W/dalvikvm( 9673): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/capsule/launcher/views/CellLayout; (346)
W/dalvikvm( 9673): Link of class 'Lcom/capsule/launcher/views/CellLayout;' failed
W/dalvikvm( 9673): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/capsule/launcher/views/DockBar; (455)
W/dalvikvm( 9673): Link of class 'Lcom/capsule/launcher/views/DockBar;' failed
E/dalvikvm( 9673): Could not find class 'com.capsule.launcher.views.DockBar', referenced from method com.capsule.launcher.views.WorkspaceHolder.onLayout
W/dalvikvm( 9673): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 456 (Lcom/capsule/launcher/views/DockBar;) in Lcom/capsule/launcher/views/WorkspaceHolder;
D/dalvikvm( 9673): VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x001b
D/AndroidRuntime( 9673): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 9673): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d6e300)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9673): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 9673): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.capsule.launcher.views.DockBar
E/AndroidRuntime( 9673):    at com.capsule.launcher.LauncherActivity.createWorkspace(LauncherActivity.java:116)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9673):    at com.capsule.launcher.LauncherActivity.onCreate(LauncherActivity.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9673):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9673):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9673):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9673):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9673):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9673):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9673):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9673):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9673):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9673):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9673):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9673):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9673):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9673):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  301):   Force finishing activity com.capsule.launcher/.LauncherActivity
D/dalvikvm( 9673): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4207K, 20% free 19381K/23943K, paused 13ms+4ms, total 52ms
W/ActivityManager(  301): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{418f0cd0 com.capsule.launcher/.LauncherActivity}
D/dalvikvm(  301): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1886K, 28% free 22076K/30279K, paused 4ms+9ms, total 99ms
W/ActivityManager(  301): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{418f0cd0 com.capsule.launcher/.LauncherActivity}
D/Finsky  ( 7843): [1] 5.onFinished: Installation state replication succeeded.
```

It worked fine in IDEA and Eclipse before!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what happend to your project, but try in Eclipse: Project--> Clean--> YourProject

Answer (score 3):

Clean and Build Your Project in Eclipse.Also check in Android Manifest file ,if launcher Activity is defined correctly with its package name.

Answer (score 2):

Its not a good idea to use it like this(**manually**) rather we can export projects from IntelliJ IDEA to Eclipse in simple steps.

please follow this standard document for the above.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/exporting-intellij-idea-project-to-eclipse.html

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

if you use librarys in your project , try in build path add to the library export

Answer (score 1):

If you do have the old working eclipse project then copy/replace all the new code and jars to it, from the IntelliJ IDEA project. Remember to copy/replace only the code and jars not the IntelliJ IDEA  specific settings files.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project which has issues and select properties.
Select the appropriate Android build (1.1, 1.5 or 1.5 with google api) and say ok.
Again right click on the project and select "Android Tools > Fix Project Properties"
Fix the imports once (if required)
Refresh the project and you should be ready to go without any manual editing

Hope this helps.